# I need build all branches in Jenkins multibranch pipeline always

Tags: jenkins

I have a project with some branches, all branches was born of master branch. When I update master branch I need do merge to other branches. I create a Multibranch pipeline in Jenkins, in al branches I put a Jenkinsfile, this make a merge with master and push the result. But when I rerun the pipeline task the  Scan Repository Log return this:

```
Checking branch jenkins
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: jenkins (still at e2879da04b4d32ad3dc8a7626bfe1e6b30ead09d)
```

How I can make to run the jenkinsfile always or change the trigger when master have new changes?

Comment: If no changes are detected, why do you need to rebuild it?

Comment: My Jenkinsfile, merge master branch with the others branches, I need check the changes on master or rebuild all branch to make this merge. But I havent idea how to do this.

Comment: Don't provide clarifications in comments. Edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I update the question, thanks.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. I am not sure if you have a problem with your git workflow, or your git workflow you designed is causing you problems.

Comment: Do not know either what you want to achieve. Are you aware that after merging a branch into "master", all other existing branches are **not** automatically rebased to the new content of master? Therefore those branches are **not** modified and builds are not automatically triggered

Comment: Thanks for all, I my problem is solved. I created a new task, this check the master branch and when is updated triggered all jobs of the multipipeline branch, is not beautiful but work.